# What happens when a 4-20mA sensor is connected in reverse to receiver?

Tags: adc, power-electronics, circuit-protection, 4-20ma

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7K9rV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I need to build a 4-20ma to 1-5v converter circuit.

I have a working model with a 24v supply and a 250 ohm resistor. Now I need to implement some protection features like reverse polarity protection.

I don't know what happens when it is connected wrong and how to protect against it.[image: 4-20ma to 1-5v converter]

Comment: Welcome to SE EE, please include a **schematic** of what you have, also include a link to the **datasheet** of the sensor.

Comment: Thanks, I added the connection diagram. But it will be any sensor model which outputs 4-20mA. On that situation how can I handle the wrong connection

Comment: That picture is not a proper schematic, it shows a "hookup". You mention a 250 ohm resistor. Then include a **schematic** showing that resistor. There's a tool to draw a schematic available when you **edit** your question. Want an answer? Then draw the schematic. It is how Electrical engineers communicate.

Comment: What's the purpose of the 250ohm? A shunt resistor for converting current to voltage?

Comment: Anyways, in general you do this with a P-channel MOSFET in series with the signal. Important to pick one with low Rds(on). Connect the gate to ground with a series resistor. One zener between source and gate. Google "MOSFET polarity protection" and you get the idea.

Comment: yes, for converting current to voltage.

Comment: Thanks @Lundin. I will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to build a 4-20ma to 1-5v converter circuit.

That's easy; it's the 250 ohm resistor shown in your top circuit.

> Now I need to implement some protection features like reverse polarity
>   protection.

Make the resistor a 3 watt type and it will take the full 24 volts forwards or backwards without being destroyed. You have to ensure that any circuit attached to the 250 ohm resistor is capable of withstanding 24 volts forwards or reverse of course but that's simple usually.

Comment: Arduino analog pin is connected across resistor.

Comment: Then fit a resistor in series with that pin so that it doesn't attach directly to the 250 ohm resistor sense input (A0 in your circuit). The resistor value should be as high as possible and, from memory I think 10 k might be as high as you can go - read the ADC specification for the ATMEGA 328. It might be that you'll need some more protection to prevent the pin becoming damaged even with out the 24 volts being reversed i.e. what if the sensor wiring got short circuited etc..

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out.